# ElasticSearch: Altering indexed version of text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch

Before the text in a field is indexed, I want to run code on it to transform it, basically what's going on here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/gsub-processor.html (but that feature isn't out yet).

For example, I want to be able to transform all `.` in a field into `-` for the indexed version.

Any advice? Doing this in elasticsearch-rails.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [char_filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-mapping-charfilter.html) where you replace all `.` into `-` but this will change the characters of the indexed terms, **not the `_source` itself**. Something like this:

```
        "char_filter" : {
            "my_mapping" : {
                "type" : "mapping",
                "mappings" : [
                  ". => -"
                ]
            }
        }
```

or use Logstash with [mutate and gsub filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html#plugins-filters-mutate-gsub) to pre-process the data before being sent to Elasticsearch. Or you do it in your own indexer (whatever that is).